# "A, B or none" input for HTML forms

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a case where I want to allow a form variable to be set to one of a set of value (in my current case true/false) or left unset (in which case no value is returned rather than some 'none' value or a blank). A check box can give the unset bit but only one set value. A radio element could work, sort of. But once a value is selected there is no way to go back to unset. All the other inputs I've looked at always set the variable no matter what.

Am I missing something or am I just going to have to accept a less-than-ideal solution?

Answer (score 1):

Three radio buttons or a `<select>` with three `<option>` will do.

Comment: I tried both before posting. For both of those, there is no way to have the query not contain the variable (as opposed to being there and havening a blank value).

Comment: @BCS: In that case put two radio buttons and a "none" button linked to a JS that resets the state of both. Not great UI, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Put three radios: A, B and None

Comment: I don't want a value of none or even a blank value. I want to not even *have* a value.

Answer (score 0):

Do a 'drop down menu' as show here: http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms11.htm

Create the default value as 'None' followed by option A and then option B.

Answer (score 0):

What about a drop down list with

```
---Please Select---
Option A
Option B
```

I've been applying to a lot of jobs online lately, and this is the route people generally have been taking.

Answer (score 0):

Would a dropdown box work?

```
<select name="choices">
  <option>(None)</option>
  <option value="a">Choice A</option>
  <option value="b">Choice B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Option none gets defaulted to blank. I guess I could filter them out on the back end but I'd rather not have to. (what happens if one of the legal values is blank?)

Comment: @BCS: Put value="none" and you're set

Comment: @nico: I don't want any value, not a blank value or even a value of "none".

Comment: @BCS: See the solution in the comment to my answer. Anyway I do not understand why you can not filter it in the backend. You are going to do different things in the 3 cases I assume, so just put 3 different values, it's as easy as that. What's the difference between writing `if(!isset($_GET["choice"])` and `if($_GET["choice"] == "none")` ???

Comment: @nico: the problem comes when I don't known in advance what value I can safely use as the "none" value. In my case the processing converts the flags into a SQL where clause: `' and '.join('%s="%s"' % (k,v) for (k,v) in args.iteritems())`. For my current case, I can pick a value that will never be seen, but In other cases, I may not know what values I need to accept till runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some javascript.  If you have jQuery there are several tri-state checkbox plugins.

For example: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/tristate-checkbox

There are also probably non jQuery scripts if you google for "tri state checkbox"

For example: http://caih.org/open-source-software/tri-state-checkbox-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 radio buttons in one group, you could hide the first 'none' radio button with CSS (`visibility:hidden;` or `display:none;`), and if that's the one still selected during your form validation, then the user hasn't chosen either of the true or false radios.

EDIT (post comments):

If no-Javascript is a requirement, then you can conditionally apply a 'hideableItem' class on the hidden radio, if scripting is disabled the worst you'll get is 3 radio for the user to choose from, as others have described. If JS is enabled, then the default radio is hidden and provides the behaviour i've described.

The conditional hiding if JS is dis/enabled technique is described here: http://lucassmith.name/2008/10/script-to-add-css-only-when-javascript-is-available.html

I use it all the time, its great.

Comment: but then how do they go back to none if they change their mind after picking true or false?

Comment: I suppose as a bare minimum you could add listeners to your radio buttons and if the user clicks the radio and it is selected, the clicked radio becomes unselected and the hidden radio becomes the selected value again. Minimal javascript involved.